# If you have two superiority dice, one from Superior Technique and another from Martial Adept, can you use both on one attack with two maneuvers?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, fighting-style, battle-master

Neither Superior Technique or Martial Adept ever mention only using one die per attack or say you follow the rules under the battle master's "Combat Superiority". They only reference you to the "maneuvers" under the Battle Master archetype and not anything else.

> Superior Technique
> TCE p41
>
> You learn one maneuver of your choice from among those available to the Battle Master archetype. If a maneuver you use requires your target to make a saving throw to resist the maneuver's effects, the saving throw DC equals 8 + your proficiency bonus + your Strength or Dexterity modifier (your choice).
>
> You gain one superiority die, which is a d6 (this die is added to any superiority dice you have from another source). This die is used to fuel your maneuvers. A superiority die is expended when you use it. You regain your expended superiority dice when you finish a short or long rest.

> Martial Adept
> PHB
> p168
>
> You have martial training that allows you to perform special combat maneuvers. You gain the following benefits:
> You learn two maneuvers of your choice from among those available to the Battle Master archetype in the fighter class. If a maneuver you use requires your target to make a saving throw to resist the maneuver's effects, the saving throw DC equals 8 + your proficiency bonus + your Strength or Dexterity modifier (your choice).
> You gain one superiority die, which is a d6 (this die is added to any superiority dice you have from another source). This die is used to fuel your maneuvers. A superiority die is expended when you use it. You regain your expended superiority dice when you finish a short or long rest.

Answer (score 12):

#### Every maneuver says you may “expend one superiority die”, and you may only use one maneuver per attack.

Every maneuver available contains the phrase:

> expend one superiority die

And the rules for maneuvers say:

> You can use only one maneuver per attack.

Since it does not say you may expend two, you may not expend two, you may only expend one, and you may only use one maneuver per attack.

Unfortunately, the rules for maneuvers do not explicitly state that the usual rules for maneuvers apply to maneuvers, but it should be clear enough that the rules for maneuvers apply to maneuvers when you’re using maneuvers.

To break this down more rigorously, we can examine it in terms of the *specific-beats-general* rule:

> The game also includes elements — class features, spells, magic items, monster abilities, and the like — that sometimes contradict a general rule. When an exception and a general rule disagree, the exception wins.

So the general rules in view here are that combat maneuvers are available to Battle Master Fighters and that you can only use one combat maneuver per attack. The specific rule here is that Martial Adept and Superior Technique create an exception to the general rule that maneuvers are only available to Battle Masters - they make combat maneuvers available to non-Battlemasters. However, *these features do not create any exception to the general rule that only one maneuver may be used per attack*. It doesn’t matter that the rule appears under the heading of the Battle Master subclass. It is still the general rule for maneuvers, and a rule would have to explicitly create an exception to it to allow multiple maneuvers to be used on a single attack.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; feel free to continue it [in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128594/discussion-on-answer-by-thomas-markov-if-you-have-two-superiority-dice-one-from).

Answer (score -5):

### **By RAW, yes you can**.

### **NO maneuver says you may only use one maneuver per attack, and the maneuvers are all the additional rules you are expected to reference.**

I know this is unintuitive and I suspect probably not what the designers would intend; however, within the written rules it is the most reasonable conclusion. Consider how your thinking might change if you never knew of the Battle Master's written restriction, and only had this feat and fighting style. It's analogous to Divine Smite and Eldritch Smite both working on the same attack, which they do.

#### **-Common misconceptions or faulty assumptions-**

1. **The rules for maneuvers say: "You can use only one maneuver per attack."**

This is only written within the ***Battle Master archetype*** under the section **"Combat Superiority"** This is its own set of rules that are only used if you are a Battle Master. These rules even specifically start by providing the conditional: "When you choose this archetype at 3rd level" Giving direct, specific and written instruction to apply these rules ONLY to the Battle Master archetype. Maneuvers granted from the Battle Master archetype and maneuvers granted from a feat or fighting style are different things with their own rules.

2. **General rules for an ability's original source apply to a source that gives the same or similar abilities.**

This might be a convenient rule that could help clarify and resolve most questions on this matter. Unfortunately, it was never written anywhere and doesn't exist so we can't use it.

3. **Even though the above rule doesn't exist it is clear that we should use it.**

This is an appeal to stone fallacy. Why is this clear? Taking this as truth we would apply all generals rules from the Battle Master's maneuvers. Just looking at the section titled **"Combat Superiority"** where the one die per attack rule is written we also have the rules:

> "You learn two additional maneuvers of your choice at 7th, 10th, and 15th level."
> "Each time you learn new maneuvers, you can also replace one maneuver
> you know with a different one."
> "You have four superiority dice, which are d8s."
> "You gain another superiority die at 7th level and one more at 15th level."

Do these also all clearly apply? If yes, then wow, almost everyone is clearly playing this very wrong. If no, then why are some clearly applied and not others, what's clear about that? More simply, it seems it isn't clear that we are supposed to apply rules that doesn't exist.

##### **-What's really going on-**

By taking the fighting style, Superior Technique TCE p41, or the feat, Martial Adept PHB p168, you follow the specific rules under that fighting style or feat.

They tell you how to use the superiority die, what die it is, where to find the maneuvers and every rule you need to use them entirely. The ONLY reference to the Battle Master archetype is to tell you where to find a list of maneuvers.

> You learn one maneuver of your choice from among those available to the Battle Master archetype.

> You learn two maneuvers of your choice from among those available to the Battle Master archetype in the fighter class.

Thus, they provide no reason or direction to go looking through all of the sections or rules under the Battle Master archetype to find alternative specific rules to impose on or override on the sufficient specific ones already given, or from sections where the specific ones already given were copied from. That would be incredulous, so unnecessarily convoluted with excess wording and distraction.

For example, both the feat and fighting style say that your superiority die is a d6. Under the section **"Combat Superiority"** within the Battle Master archetype it says your superiority die are d8 and that they change when you go up in level.

There seems to be a very specific attempt by the designers to have this feat and fighting style be fully self contained mechanically within the rules. They went so far as to mention how a DC will be calculated for a very small portion of the maneuvers.

This exact sentence appears in both the feat and fighting style:

> If a maneuver you use requires your target to make a saving throw to resist the maneuver's effects, the saving throw DC equals 8 + your proficiency bonus + your Strength or Dexterity modifier (your choice).

A section under the Battle Master archetype titled **"Combat Superiority"**
contains the sentence:

> Some of your maneuvers require your target to make a saving throw to resist the maneuver's effects. The saving throw DC is calculated as follows:
> Maneuver save DC = 8 + your proficiency bonus + your Strength or Dexterity modifier (your choice)

If the designers wanted anyone to reference or use the rules for **"Combat Superiority"** They would have simply instructed them to do so within the writing of the fighting style or the feat. Rather, they copied the parts of the rules they needed to arbitrate the mechanics from **"Combat Superiority"** almost verbatim and put it within the rules for the fighting style and feat, so that no one needed to find this section and use it. They also wanted to change the die size from a d8 starting size to a permanent d6, specifically having a reason to guide a player away from ever referencing this extra specific set of rules. It would be very obtuse and peculiar to copy parts of the rules over, and then also expect someone to find the section they copied them from and use all of its rules instead, including the parts they copied over and the parts that would be in direct contradiction, like the die size. This would be an incorrigible logical problem.

**"Combat Superiority"** is a specific set of rules that pertains only to Battle Master archetype.

Further, the designers expected you to be able to get more than one superiority die without using the Battle Master archetype.

Both this feat and fighting style use the same sentence:

> You gain one superiority die, which is a d6 (this die is added to any superiority dice you have from another source).

They use the words *"any superiority dice you have from another source"* instead of from the Battle Master archetype.

Finally, a player could flip to PHB p74 to find the maneuvers list and have every single rule they need to use their new ability in full and never even see the page where **"Combat Superiority"** is contained, and they would have no reason to go looking for it.

Comment: I think your are wayyyy overselling how far away the maneuverrules and the maneuver lost are from one another. Reading your answer, you make it seem like the rules are in one chapter, and the maneuver list is in a totally different chapter, when in reality, *the list of maneuvers is immediately following the short list of subclass features.* The only reason they’re on separate pages in the PHB is the right side of the page with rules has a full column image of a tapestry. “Incredulous and highly confusing” is probably an exaggeration.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov So a player could flip to the maneuvers list and pick a maneuver and have everything they need to use the ability they got and never even see the "Combat Superiority" section at all? Good to know.

Comment: Maybe, but that’s not really how people navigate books. But if you want to make an an argument for a ruling based on the possibility of someone finding the maneuver list without using the table contents, be my guest; it’s just a really odd piece of evidence to think has any meaning.

Comment: You could still use the table contents to find were fighters would be, but you could also from there skip over the pages that have unreferenced and unneeded rules to find the one with the maneuvers that you were instructed to find and use. Or maybe when flipping to p70 for fighters, you find p74 with maneuvers first.

Comment: It may be worth noting that even if a DM accepts this reading, it definitely stops working if you are also a Battle Master. Battle Masters specifically can only use one maneuver per attack.